# Chrome browser on Mac shows random text instead of English in settings

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm getting complete nonsense text in my Google Chrome settings. And when I type, I get completely wrong characters... but only in settings. the masthead search and other websites display correctly. All other programs and web browsers are working fine.[image: chrome settings image]
I've searched for a fix but found nothing.
I've tried:
dumping the preferences for Chrome
resetting settings
uninstalling and reinstalling chrome altogether
checking for malware with Malwarebytes and so far nothing fixes it.
logged in with a different user. same issues in settings so assume it's a local problem and not a user settings problem.
restarted in safe mode and text is fine. created an alternate admin user and text was fine. So cleaned all caches with Ventura Cache Cleaner and still have the same issue on my normal admin settings.
This is only happening on my desktop computer. my MacBook displays settings correctly so I don't think it's related to my google account being corrupted. The computer is a Mac running OS 13.2.1 and Google Chrome is the latest version 111.0.5563.64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER FOUND. removed the recently added font ROBOTO and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Welcome!  I’m pleased youngot your situation resolved, but you might want to expand in your answer for future readers who run into your or a similar issue.  What isn”ROBOTO”? There”s no context here.

Comment: I'm actually not sure WHY the Roboto font was the culprit. But removing it did resolve the issue. I found the answer after searching extensively on the web and found the answer in a Google forum. The irony is I had recently downloaded the Roboto font FROM GOOGLE directly: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/85825818/google-chrome-settings-page-text-displays-as-gibberish?hl=en&fbclid=IwAR2LEqsP8CB2BJQjmh5eIWa1wjkjvjMNFNgcH6UWwQj9rIkUggLO48Y5kLY

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.

Comment: done. I didn't realize that was an option. new to this forum.